# I cant Update Google play services as it says "Authentication is required. You need to sign into your google account"

Tags: google-play-services, snapchat

I keep getting nonification updates the I need to Update Google Play services and that Google Play services wont run unless updated, wh I click on the nonification. It bring me to Googl
play services but it says "Authentication is required. You need to sign into your google account which I checked in Accounts, I was signed in. I need to get the Play services to work as most of my apps like Snapchat rely on it.

Comment: I think you have signed up with an corporate email(e.g. kiara@abc.com) which are purchased domains from google. I may have seen problems of these types with this. If you did that, I suggest remove that account and sign up with an regular gmail address.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update Google settings, front-end for Google Play Store and other Google stuff. Go to *Settings* -> *Apps* -> *Google Play Services* and uninstall the updates. Leave the phone on WiFi. It will update automatically.